# GKE Ingress Timeout Values

Tags: websocket, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'd like to use websockets in my web application. Right now my websocket disconnects and reconnects every 30 seconds, which is the default timeout in GKE Ingress. I tried the following to change timeout values:

```
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "300"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: "300"
    nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.org/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
```

After recreating the ingress through `kubectl` the timeout value remains 30 seconds:
[image]

I also tried to create a backend configuration as described here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-backend-service

The timeout value still remained unchanged at 30 seconds.

Is there a way to increase timeout value through annotations in .yml file? I could edit the timeout value through the web interface but I'd rather use .yml files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I upgraded my master and its nodes to version 1.14 and then the backend config approach worked.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seems like an issue with the version.

As long as the GKE version is 1.11.3-gke.18 and above as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-backend-service#overview), you should be able to update the [timeoutSec](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#create-backend-service) value by configuring the 'BackendConfig' as explained in the [help center article](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-backend-service#creating_a_backendconfig).

I changed the timeoutSec value by editing the example [manifest](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-backend-service#creating_a_backendconfig) and then updating the BackendConfig (in my GKE 1.13.11-gke.14 cluster) using "`kubectl apply -f my-bsc-backendconfig.yaml`
" command.